# Mobile Phone tethering in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I have a Nokia C3-01.5 mobile phone I use it to get access to the internet on occasions from my laptop. I recently changed from Windows XP to Ubuntu 12.10. Tethering worked fine with blue tooth but I couldn't get my wireless to work. I changed to version 13.10 and I could then get my wireless to work but not tethering. I have now installed and updated version 14.04. My wireless works but I still can not get tethering to work either via blue tooth or USB Cable. After pairing the phone I select the "Access the Internet using your mobile phone (DUN) option but get an error message "Error timed out detecting phone details."
Can someone please tell me how I can get DUN through my phone in Ubuntu 14.04? I looked at some answers to similar problems when I had Version 13.10 installed and one suggested installing Modemanager but all this did was to stop my wireless working.

Comment: When you connect the phone and try to tether do you see any errors in /var/log/syslog?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to get bluetooth tethering working in 14.04 with my lg phone. AT&T would not authorize my phone to do this without upgrading to a 5gb+ plan.

I installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.nicumaru.bluetoothtetheronoff
and this seems to flip the switch allowing me to tether that AT&T and/or LG was blocking.